# Printing specific character from a string in C

Tags: c, string, printf

I'm working on prefixing of a string for example : `com` should give me `c` `co` `com`.
I know to print a character in this was `printf("%.5s",string)` to print the first five values. I want to do this in a loop instead of 5 how can I replace it with `i` which is a incrementing value,something like this `printf("%.is",string)`. how can I obtain this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `printf` format specifiers, all field widths (before the dot) and precisions (after the dot) can be given as asterisk `*`. For each asterisk, there must be one additional `int` argument before the printed object.

So, for your problem:

```
printf("%.*s", i, string);
```

Note that the additional parameter must be an `int`, so if you have another integer type, you should cast it:

```
size_t len = strlen(len);
if (len > 2) printf("%.*s", (int) (len - 2), string);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the simplest way of achieving what you want.

```
printf("%.*s\n", i, string);
```

If you want to generate the format string, you can do it too

```
char format[100]; /* the size should be estimated by you */

snprintf(format, sizeof(format), "%%.%ds", i);
printf(format, string)
```

check the `snprintf()` return value to ensure that the string was not truncated, if you choos a reasonable size for the format string it will be unlikely, but you should check anyway.

Above, the format specifier means

- A literal `"%"`
- Then a `"."`
- Then the integer `"%d"`
- Then the letter `"s"`

so the resulting string will be the format string you need to pass to `printf()`.

Comment: can u please explain it?

Comment: Why are you asking in my answer?

Comment: `sizeof(int)*CHAR_BIT / 3` is enough for `INT_MAX` in decimal, so a buffer `char format[3 + sizeof(int)*CHAR_BIT/3 + 2];` is sufficient in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
char s[] = "com";  
for(size_t i = 1; i <= strlen(s); i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < i; j++)  
         printf("%c", s[j]);
    printf(" ");  
}
```

Comment: @Gopi; I didn't downvoted, but your answer is wrong.

Comment: That should be `sizeof` (or `strlen(...) + 1`, but maybe put it outside the loop) to get `c co com `.

Comment: And also, don't use `strlen()` that way. Store it somewhere instead of calling it on each iteration.

Comment: @iharob; Modern compilers are smart enough to optimize it.